# How to avoid too many if condition when the return type is not known?

Tags: java, design-patterns

How to avoid too many if condition when the return type is dynamic?

I understand that we can create a hashmap with key and value if the condition and the value is  static too avoid too many if conditions.

In the below example the price for each month is different from customer to 
customer...i need to add 12 if statements for the same...assume if the field is something 
 other than the month...they i may endup with more than 100 or 200 if's...ex: for year...1900 to 2000

```
Example,

public String getPrice(int Month) {
   String price = "";
   switch (month) {
        case 1:
          price = customerTable.getJanPrice();
          break;
        case 2:
          price = customerTable.getFebPrice();
          break;
         ...........
    }
    return price;
}
```

Could you please help me out with your suggestions/comments?

Thanks,
Kathir

Comment: Can't you have your customer table use the month instead ? `customerTable.getPrice(int month)`

Comment: What is the usage contexte of customerTable ? In the UI or in a database storage ?

Comment: hmm, can you provide code for `customerTable.getJanPrice()` and other methods which are making calculations ,to have a closer look and understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an Enum with the prices that you want.

```
public enum Month 
{
    SEPTEMBER (3.33),
    OCTOBER (4.85),
    NOVEMBER (5.98),
    etc ;

    public final double Price;

    Month(double monthPrice)
    {
        this.Price = monthPrice;
    }        
}
```

Then to access that price:

```
Month.SEPTEMBER.Price
```

**EDIT**
Because the data is changed at runtime and their are an 'infinite' amount of possibilities using Classes would be a more manageable option.

```
public class Year
{   
    public final List<Month> Months;

    public Year(List<Month> months)
    {
        Months = months;
    }
}

public class Month
{
    public final double Price;

    public Month(double price)
    {
        Price = price;
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP says that it could also be a year with 100s of possible values.

Comment: The problem is the prices are not static, it is dynamic from the table. We know it in the runtime.

Comment: How are you getting populating the prices?

Comment: price is a databased stored value which differs from customer to customer.

Comment: It really depends on the database usually I like to "code first" before I start creating the database. I hope I've helped a little.

Comment: It means the only way to iterate the entire set and create the year object with list of months with price after getting values from the DB and use the same. am i right?

Comment: Yes you could do it this way.

Comment: In the above approach i will process all the values and stores in a map for each row and gets a single value. Why i should process and save all the values when i need a single value from a particular month.

Comment: Because I'm not sure how you get the prices.

Answer (score 0):

What if (assuming here) the returned 'dataobject' for each customer was some sort of hashmap (kv-store) .

Then using some convention you could use a `<day,month,year>`-combi to build a key which is used to lookup the price for that specific combination in the returned dataobject.